# Grails integration test on a service: cannot set property on null object

Tags: grails, service, nullpointerexception, spock

I am using `Grails 2.4.4` for my application, and using `spock` framework for tests.

```
class TaxpayerService {
    static transactional = false

    def springSecurityService

    def setImporterDetails(TvfGen tvfGen) {
        if (isTrader()) {
            String taxPayerCode = springSecurityService?.principal?.getAt("tin")
            def importerDetails = HistorizationSupport.withHistorizedFinder(BusinessLogicUtils.getWorkingDate(tvfGen)) {
                Company.findByCode(taxPayerCode)
            }

            if (importerDetails) {
                tvfGen.with {
                    impTaxPayerAcc = taxPayerCode
                    impName = importerDetails.name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my integration test:

```
@Build([TvfGen])
class TaxpayerServiceSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    def taxpayerService
    def springSecurityService

    void setup() {
    }

    void tearDown() {
        // Tear down logic here
    }

    void "test set importer details"() {
        given:
        def tvfGen = TvfGen.build()
        springSecurityService = [principal: [tin: '0815790B', authorities: [ROLE_TRADER]]]
        taxpayerService.springSecurityService = springSecurityService
        taxpayerService.setImporterDetails(tvfGen)

        expect:
        tvfGen.impName == 'OMNI VALUE'
    }
}
```

As a result I receive an error:

```
Cannot set property 'springSecurityService' on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'springSecurityService' on null object
    at TaxpayerServiceSpec.test set importer details(TaxpayerServiceSpec.groovy:34)
```

Comment: What's the `@Build` annotation for?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith see this plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data

Comment: You do not need to use `@Build` in IntegrationSpec. All domain classes will have build() available in Integration specs. Can you all add all the imports in the test class? Make sure `IntegrationSpec ` is not imported from the grails spock plugin but from spock core (`grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec`) which is present in grails core by default.

Comment: @dmahapatro thanks, it appears, that the problem was because of `@Build` annotation.